# Problema con for y contador

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en un script que pueda resolver puzles.

La función piezas extrae la información del array `$array y la divide en las correspondientes piezas, que son 16 de piezas de 4 caras (digitos) cada una. En el array los dos primeros dígitos indican en ancho y alto del puzle y el resto de números son las piezas del puzle.

Esta función funciona perfectamente, ahora el problema que tengo es que solo hay 4 piezas con dos ceros en sus fichas, estos números indican con que otra pieza encajarían, el 1 con el 1, el 2 con el 2, etc... pero el 0 indica que es un borde, por lo que dos 0 indican que esa pieza debe ir en una esquina.

Muy bien, sabiendo esto, recorro el array de todas las piezas haciendo un `sizeof($piezas)`, por cada una de esta quiero recorrer sus 4 posiciones y ver si tras recorrerlas hay 2 ceros en esa pieza, pero únicamente me esta sacando los números de las piezas, ahora mismo `echo $contador` me devuelve:

> 0123456789101112131415

lo cual no es para nada lo que quiero, espero haber sido claro, si tenéis alguna duda al respecto comentarlo, muchas gracias por todo de antemano!

```
<?php

$array = [4, 4,
    2, 5, 4, 0,
    2, 1, 4, 2,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    4, 4, 0, 3,
    0, 0, 4, 3,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 4, 0, 0,
    4, 4, 3, 5,
    5, 5, 2, 4,
    1, 1, 0, 5,
    4, 1, 0, 4,
    1, 0, 2, 4,
    3, 5, 1, 2,
    1, 4, 2, 0,
    0, 1, 5, 2,
    1, 5, 0, 4];


$matriz = array(array());
$borde = array();

function piezas($arrayPiezas){

    $length = count($arrayPiezas);
    $alto = $arrayPiezas[0];
    $ancho = $arrayPiezas[1];
    global $matriz;
    
    $arrPiezas = array_slice($arrayPiezas, 2);

    for($i = 1; $i < ($length/$alto); $i++){
        
        for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){

            $matriz[$i-1][$j] = $arrPiezas[0];
            array_shift($arrPiezas);

        }
    }
}

function colocarPiezas($piezas){

    

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($piezas); $i++) {

        for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){
           $contador = 0;
            if($piezas[$i][$j] == 0){

                $contador++;
                print_r($piezas[$i][$j]);
                echo $contador;
            }
         
        }
    }
}




piezas($array);

colocarPiezas($matriz);



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa que escriba una respuesta, quizá sería mejor un comentario.

Si quieres usar la variable $contador para saber la cantidad de bordes (zeros) que tiene una pieza deberías inizializar la variable a 0 antes de la inspeccion de cada pieza:

```
<?php
function colocarPiezas($piezas){

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($piezas); $i++) {

        for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){

            $contador = 0;

            if($piezas[$i][$j] == 0){

                $contador++;
                if($contador == 2){
                    print_r($piezas[$i]);
                    echo "ES UNA ESQUINA!";
                }
            }
         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero sigue sin funcionar, en vez de recibir '0123456789101112131415', recibo '1111111111111111', se te ocurre porque?

Comment: @DanielMorales según mi propuesta, en la variable contador se almacenan el número de esquinas de cada pieza inspeccionada. Entonces cuando contador llegue a 2 se imprime la pieza inspeccionada. Veo que has editado tu pregunta moviendo solo la línea donde se inicializa el contador, pero no has añadido la comprobación de que este sea 2 ( cuando la pieza tenga dos lados) que sería el "if($contador == 2) {......."